# How to parameterize makefile targets

Tags: makefile

I got a Makefile that does build a 32 and a 64 bit version of a project:

```
#############################
# 32 bit variant of test tool
#############################
hidtest_32: $(OBJS_32)
    $(CXX_32) -m32 -g $^ $(LIBS) -o hidtest_32

hid_32.o: hid.c
    $(CC_32) -m32 $(CFLAGS) $< -o hid_32.o

../hidtest/hidtest_32.o: ../hidtest/hidtest.cpp
    $(CC_32) -m32 $(CFLAGS) $< -o ../hidtest/hidtest_32.o


#############################
# 64 bit variant of test tool
#############################
hidtest_64: $(OBJS_64)
    $(CXX_64) -m64 -g $^ $(LIBS) -o hidtest_64

hid_64.o: hid.c
    $(CC_64) -m64 $(CFLAGS) $< -o hid_64.o

../hidtest/hidtest_64.o: ../hidtest/hidtest.cpp
    $(CC_64) -m64 $(CFLAGS) $< -o ../hidtest/hidtest_64.o
```

As you can see both variants use the exact same build procedure, except that the number `32` has been replaced with `64`.

I've tried something like

```
hidtest64: ARCH=64
hidtest64: hidtest_64
hidtest32: ARCH=32
hidtest32: hidtest_32

hidtest_%: $(OBJS_$(ARCH))
   $(CXX_$(ARCH)) -m$(ARCH) -g $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

which does not work as expected. I guess I would need to access the part of the target that matched `%`, which I wasn't able to do.

Is there a way to consolidate the two variants into a single (parameterized) one?

Comment: Seems okay to me, just tested. What happens? Could you add `@echo` in front of the compile line and show us the output of `make hidtest64` and `make hidtest32` ?

Comment: @kebs That can't possibly work. In `hidtest: ARCH=64` the ARCH=64 part is a dependency, not a variable assignment to ARCH.

Comment: It seems like the hidtest_% target does not correctly evaluate the "$(OBJS_$(ARCH))" dependencies. There's an error stating that the targets contained in OBJS_32 / OBJS_64 have not been executed.

Comment: `hidtest32: ARCH=32` says: target "hidtest32" depends on the target "ARCH=32"

Comment: @Jens: Nope, to me this is a "Target-specific Variable assignment", see  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific

Comment: @k_wave Yeah, I missed the point about the dependency on `OBJS_$(ARCH)`

Comment: Building 32-bit vs 64-bit versions sounds like a job for `configure`, not for `make`. The makefile should only build the single verison that `configure` chose, but support out-of-tree builds.

Comment: @kebs You are making the assumption "All the world's a GNU make" :-) The tags do not include GNU make.

Comment: @Jens You are right, I don't know anything about non-gnu make, so I assumed they all behaved similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make You can write a function (a callable macro). Single `$` is substituted during `$(call ...)` double `$` is substituted when doing `$(eval $(call ...))`. Background information [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function).

```
define add_target
  $(info compiling hidtest_$(1)) # logged when doing $(call ...)
  $$(info evaluating hidtest_$(1)) # logged when doing $(eval $(call ...))

  hidtest_$(1): $(OBJS_$(1))
    $(CXX_$(1)) -m$(1) -g $$^ $(LIBS_$(1)) -o $$@
endef

$(eval $(call add_target,32))
$(eval $(call add_target,64))
```

Comment: Can't get it working, seems like the macro does not generate the targets for 64 and 32 bit. "no rule found to make hidtest_32" Can you add an example on how to call the targets generated by this macro?

Comment: does it log "compiling hidtest_34" and "evaluating hidtest_32" ?

Comment: I figured it out: There are three small errors in your code: 1) `$(call add_target 32)` has to be `$(call add_target,32)` (missing comma). 2) everything in the define must not have any indent. 3) endef is missing.